# Issue Using Alpine.js with Vite in a fresh Laravel 10 installation

Tags: javascript, vite, alpine.js, laravel-10

I've been attempting to use Vite for the first time, I'm more familiar with Laravel Mix. It appears that when I include alpine functions in app.js and build with `npm run build` those functions cannot be run from the directives in the markup. Heres my code:

in `index.blade.php`:

```
<div
    class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4"
    x-data="solar"
>
    <form @submit.prevent="addComponent">
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-select-input id="component" :items="$products->pluck('name', 'id')"></x-select-input>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-primary-button>Add Component</x-primary-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="w-96">
        <template x-for="component in components">
            <li
                class="w-full border-b-2 border-neutral-100 border-opacity-100 py-4 dark:border-opacity-50"
                x-text="component.name" >
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in `app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();


document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('solar', () => ({

        components: [],

        addComponent(elem) {
            let item = document.getElementById('component');
            this.components.push({
                id: item.value,
                name: item.options[item.selectedIndex].text,
            });
        },
    }));
});
```

And in `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

If include the same `Alpine.data()` function in a script tag within the view (index.blade.php), it works flawlessly: but when it's placed within app.js and included in the resulting build I get the error:

```
Alpine Expression Error: addComponent is not defined

Expression: "addComponent"
```

How can I solve this and put my functions in the Vite build instead of in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [alpine.js docs](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation#as-a-module):

> If you imported Alpine into a bundle, you have to make sure you are registering any extension code IN BETWEEN when you import the `Alpine` global object, and when you initialize Alpine by calling `Alpine.start()`.

To me it looks like this shouldn't be anything but just an ordering issue (I've had the same problem myself before). Call `Alpine.start()` **AFTER** all of your alpine.js code. Your `app.js` should look something like this:

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.data('solar', () => ({ ... }));

Alpine.start();
```

Note that you don't need the `'alpine:init'` event listener when using a build system like this. Have a look at [this section](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#registering-from-a-bundle) in the docs for an example. I'd recommend extracting all of your alpine.js components out of `app.js` into individual files for better separation of concerns, and of course to prevent your `app.js` from becoming too bloated when you start adding more components. Something like this:

```js
// app.js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

import component1 from './alpine_components/component1.js';
import component2 from './alpine_components/component2.js';
...

Alpine.data('component1', component1);
Alpine.data('component2', component2);
...

Alpine.start();
```

```js
// alpine_components/component1.js
export default () => ({
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did read that section of the docs, but I assumed it meant when building custom plugins.  Your extra advice is also appreciated. I'm learning Alpine.js as well.